# Enable multiple GDAL threads for qgis2web?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, multithreading

I'm using qgis2web plugin for a project that has a raster base map and many layers. It works well but exporting is slow, taking 16 minutes. gdalwarp.exe seems to use only one thread (the CPU has eight). I have set GDAL_NUM_THREADS to 7 in the general settings and also project settings but it doesn't seem to do a difference.

Starting from a command prompt and setting GDAL_NUM_THREADS doesn't seem to help either. Using OSGEO4WIN shell doesn't help either.

Is it possible to enable multiple GDAL threads for QGIS plugins?

Windows 7 Enterprise

QGIS 2.18.7 (not newest, but that's what is installed)

qgis2web 2.33.1